# How to prevent side effects from application settings?

Tags: excel, vba

### Application Settings

A common technique for improving code performance is by changing settings in the [excel.application(object)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application(object)). Some of the most notable settings are:

- `Application.Calculation`
- `Application.ScreenUpdating`
- `Application.EnableEvents`

### Side Effect Issue

The issue I have come across, especially when working in other peoples code, is that many of these settings are global by nature and produce unwanted side effects in the code.

Below I have written an **overly simplified example** showing what I'm talking about:

```vb
Private Sub main()
    ' Turn off the calculation for some good reason
    Application.calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    someChildProcedure
    
    ' Do something...
    ' Woops! This main process is expecting calculation to be
    ' set to manual! The child call messed this up :/
    
    ' This is where the main process expected the state
    ' to change, But in reality it was done early :(
    Application.calculation = xlCalculationManual
End Sub

Private Sub someChildProcedure()
    Application.calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    ' Do something...
    
    ' Reset the state
    ' Woops, the calling code won't expect this!!
    Application.calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

### The Question

Obviously, if we follow code we can track the state of the settings and make adjustments in the code, but what I have found that this is often a maintenance headache.

With this in mind, how can we prevent these undesired side effects from occurring when working with application settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Caching the settings

A simple way to prevent these side effects is by capturing the current setting into a variable, and then at the end of the code change the setting back to it's previous state.

```vb
Private Sub main()
    ' Turn off the calculation for some good reason
    Application.calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    someChildProcedure
    
    ' Do something...
    ' Yay, not effected by the child Call anymore :)
    
    Application.calculation = xlCalculationManual
End Sub

Private Sub someChildProcedure()
    ' Capture the current state
    Dim previousCalculationState As XlCalculation
    previousCalculationState = Application.calculation
    
    Application.calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    ' Do something...
    
    ' Reset the state to the chached value
    Application.calculation = previousCalculationState
End Sub
```

### Issue With This Strategy

Capturing the variable worked!

The issue now is that to run this for a single setting it took 4 lines of code. Imagine using this technique with multiple settings — 4 settings would be a whopping 16 lines of boilerplate code just for one procedure! Do this throughout your code and it will quickly become a mess.

### A Better Caching Solution

We need a Class to do this caching for us. It is simple, we will want methods for `CaptureCurrentSettings`, `EnablePerformanceSettings`, and `ResetSettingsToLastCapture`.

As a bonus, we can use the `Initialize` event to capture the current settings and `Terminate` event to reset the settings.

Below is the Class named `ApplicationSettings`:

```vb
''
' A Simple Class that turns on Excel Performance
' settings.
'
' This benefit of using this class is
' that it captures the current settings before
' changing anything. This makes it nice as it
' is now less prone to affecting other sections
' of code that are maybe already changed the state
' of these settings and are expecting them not to have
' changed.
'
' With new PerformanceSettings
'    .EnablePerformanceSettings
'    ' Do something that is normally poor performance
' End With
'
' @author Robert Todar <robert@roberttodar.com>
''
Option Explicit

Private Type State
    ResetOnTermination As Boolean
    calculation As XlCalculation
    displayAlerts As Boolean
    screenUpdating As Boolean
    enableAnimations As Boolean
    enableEvents As Boolean
    displayStatusBar As Boolean
    printCommunication As Boolean
End Type

Private this As State

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    ' By default this class will reset all settings
    ' once terminated.
    this.ResetOnTermination = True
    
    ' On initialization capture the current settings.
    ' This can be updated at any time by calling
    ' `CaptureCurrentSettings`
    CaptureCurrentSettings
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    ' The thinking on this is that we always want to return the
    ' state back to the initial so that we are not messing with
    ' the Global state that other functions/subs might be counting
    ' on.
    If this.ResetOnTermination Then
        ResetSettingsToLastCapture
    End If
End Sub

Public Property Let ResetOnTermination(ByVal Value As Boolean)
    this.ResetOnTermination = Value
End Property

Public Property Get ResetOnTermination() As Boolean
    ResetOnTermination = this.ResetOnTermination
End Property

Public Sub CaptureCurrentSettings()
    With Application
        this.calculation = .calculation
        this.displayAlerts = .displayAlerts
        this.screenUpdating = .screenUpdating
        this.enableAnimations = .enableAnimations
        this.enableEvents = .enableEvents
        this.displayStatusBar = .displayStatusBar
        this.printCommunication = .printCommunication
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub ResetSettingsToLastCapture()
    With Application
        .calculation = this.calculation
        .displayAlerts = this.displayAlerts
        .screenUpdating = this.screenUpdating
        .enableAnimations = this.enableAnimations
        .enableEvents = this.enableEvents
        .displayStatusBar = this.displayStatusBar
        .printCommunication = this.printCommunication
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub EnablePerformanceSettings( _
    Optional calculation As XlCalculation = xlCalculationManual, _
    Optional displayAlerts As Boolean = False, _
    Optional screenUpdating As Boolean = False, _
    Optional enableAnimations As Boolean = False, _
    Optional enableEvents As Boolean = False, _
    Optional displayStatusBar As Boolean = False, _
    Optional printCommunication As Boolean = False _
)
    With Application
        .calculation = calculation
        .displayAlerts = displayAlerts
        .screenUpdating = screenUpdating
        .enableAnimations = enableAnimations
        .enableEvents = enableEvents
        .displayStatusBar = displayStatusBar
        .printCommunication = printCommunication
    End With
End Sub
```

Using this Class is simple, simply use a `With` statement and call `.EnablePerformanceSettings` providing any optional overrides for the settings.

```vb
Private Sub DemoPerformanceSettings()
    With New ApplicationSettings
        ' This method has optional arguments
        ' for overriding any of the settings
        .EnablePerformanceSettings
        
        ' Do something...
        
    ' The settings will reset on termination
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Why did you post a question that you had the answer for? Plus the speed up process is always recommended, if the coder does not know where computations should be performed, where events need to be enabled and such, I'd be skeptical on how well the coder is related to know the logic behind it.

Comment: I recently inherited a bunch of code that is a huge mess in multiple ways, and I needed to add code to it. As I was doing so I was coming across this issue quite a bit, and wanted to find a solution. Since I couldn't find a solution on SO I came up with this solution and wanted to share it to help others. SO gives the option to answer you own questions, and people who have done that in the past have helped me as well. See [can-you-answer-your-own-questions-on-stack-overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250204/can-you-answer-your-own-questions-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: Additionally see SO own page [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: While you can answer your own questions, I think this scenario falls under what [Louis](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253050/3221380) stated in his answer `answerable by reading the fine manual`,again, this is my solely opinion. Let the community decide and I hope is useful for someone.

Comment: I've used the same technique for years. See [here](https://github.com/cristianbuse/VBA-FastExcelUDFs/blob/master/Code%20Modules/ExcelAppState.cls). It is the best approach as each time we want to store state, turn off, do something and finally restore state (while having a failsafe in the termination event). The state should never be assumed to be on/off hence having instances of the state within each separate method scope is the best and cleanest approach.

Comment: Thank you for sharing! I recently found your GitHub and enjoyed some of your work, but I definitely missed this one. Appreciate to hear I'm not the only one seeing a benefit here :)